# Call to firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, alamofire

I'm attempting to make a call to the real time database that I have constructed in firebase. I have utilized the three different methods stated in the documentation, however, I still get an unacceptable access code.

Below are the current code and method that I am using.

```
 let apiToContact = "https://gameofchats-c29ab.firebaseio.com/users.json?auth=AIzaSyBK3J4tzVQNJlhqqmYPRWXlJqnzFB1Hj4k"


    let request = Alamofire.request(apiToContact, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: nil)
    request.validate().responseJSON(){ response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                let allEventData = json["events"].arrayValue
                // Do what you need to with JSON here!
                // print(json)
                // print("\n\nlook here\n\n")
                // print(allRestaurantData)
                // The rest is all boiler plate code you'll use for API requests
                print("\n\nlook here\n\n")
                print(allEventData)

                // var firstRestaurant = allRestaurantData[0]
                //print(firstRestaurant)

                // will populate all Restaurants Array with restaurant objects
                /*
                for restaurantStruct in allRestaurantData {
                    self.allRestaurants.append(Restaurants(json: restaurantStruct))
                }

                     for restaurantsName in self.allRestaurants{
                     print(restaurantsName.restaurantApiKey)
                     print("\n")
                 }
                 */
                // will take the imageUrl array and populate it with the logoURL of the restaurants for later user
              /*  for images in self.allRestaurants{
                    self.imageUrl.append(images.logoUrl)
                    print(images.logoUrl)
                    print("\n")
                }

                */

            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not using Firebase API for iOS?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: can I not do this?

Comment: I've explored Firebase only for iOS/Android. However, I'd like to know if there's reason not to use iOS API?